# change style when line breaks

Tags: html, css

I have an HTML list with `display: inline-block` which I want to separate with a line to make a footer menu.
For that I apply a left border for every list item that has an item before. However, when screen is smaller and the line breaks, the first item in the second line shows the border.

How can I hide the border on the first item on the second line once the line breaks?

Here is a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ur7dyL7u/3/

```
<style type="text/css">
li {
    line-height: 24px;
    display: inline-block;
    border-right: none;
}

li~li {
    border-left: red 2px solid;
    padding-left: 5px;
}

div{
       text-align:center;
}

</style>
<div>
<ul>
    <li>Item nr 1</li>
    <li>Item nr 2</li>
    <li>Item nr 3</li>
    <li>Item nr 4</li>
    <li>Item nr 5</li>
    <li>Item nr 6</li>
    <li>Item nr 7</li>
    <li>Item nr 8</li>
    <li>Item nr 9</li>
    <li>Item nr 10</li>
</ul>
<div>
```

Comment: Would you be able to break your list in to sub lists?

Comment: I guess that would require some JS and my goal is to use CSS only.

Answer (score 4):

I think there is no way to do that the way you want to, you will have to change the approach;

I tried those styles to achieve what you want:

```
ul{
  padding:0; overflow:hidden;
}
li {
    line-height: 24px;
    display: inline-block;
    border-right: none;
    padding-left: 5px;
}
li~li {
    box-shadow: -2px 0px 0px red;
}
```

Instead of a border, I use box shadow that is outside the box and set overflow hidden to the list so it will always hide the shadow of the first element on each line.

Here is a working example: https://jsfiddle.net/2o18jkfL/

Another one that "works" with text-align:center

http://codepen.io/sergio0983/pen/YpKxzQ

**EDIT**

Different approach using :before to cover the line on the first item in each line:

http://codepen.io/sergio0983/pen/eBOEpY

Comment: You approach is interesting however it doesn't work when text is centre aligned. Sorry, forgot to add that.

Comment: This is only an example; what I wanted to tell is that you will need css tricks rather than any rule, and you will have to be creaive . BTW, what do you mean with text is center aligned?? it should work with text-align center too

Comment: I got your point. Yes, we need tricks. 
Add body {text-align:center;} to your fiddle and you'll see that it wont work when centred.

Comment: add float:left ^^

Comment: Sure, and then direction: rtl;

Comment: rtl?? to achieve what??

Comment: Well, you said to use float:left, when I said that I want the text centred. I thought your were joking, so I added to the joke :P

Comment: See the codepen example; it works perfectly when float:left is added to li selector; also I added another approach using :before, but it´s a bit more... strange

Comment: When you use float:left you null the body{text-align:center} and you get the text aligned again to the left. I want everything centered like in my fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ur7dyL7u/3/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/127214/discussion-between-sergio0983-and-beowulf).

Answer (score 0):

If you have no problem with having a separation in the first line when line-breaks you can do this:

Instead of using `border-left` use `border-right` in all your `li` elements except the last one.

```css
ul {
  text-align: center;
}
li {
  line-height: 14px;
  display: inline-block;
}
li:not(:last-child) {
  border-right: red 1px solid;
  padding-right: 10px;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>Item nr 1</li>
  <li>Item nr 2</li>
  <li>Item nr 3</li>
  <li>Item nr 4</li>
  <li>Item nr 5</li>
  <li>Item nr 6</li>
  <li>Item nr 7</li>
  <li>Item nr 8</li>
  <li>Item nr 9</li>
  <li>Item nr 10</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: The last item in the first line still has the border on the right, and I only need it to separate item. It shouldn't show in the end or in the beginning of any line.